# android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android

I'm getting following error

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Comment: Please add code also.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is probably child of a `LinearLayout` (and not child of a `ConstraintLayout`). So, you have to use:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams()
```

Some background: If you have this layout, for example

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/child_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you try to get the `LayoutParams` from `child_view`, you will get a instance of a `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` (because `child_view` is child of a `LinearLayout`).

On the other hand:

```
<ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/child_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

This gives you `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams` object.

So, you have to ensure your java code is properly reflecting your layout.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you can not cast LayoutParams of one layout to the another. It is tied to the specific layout type. So change your layout from Linear to Constraint.